# How can I load camera preview instead of a image

Tags: android-bitmap, face-detection, android-camera2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RvkO.png)
I'm Making an android app.
Well, this is a sample code for face detection provided by google.
Instead of using a jpeg file, I want to use my camera preview .
How should I change the code? It would be very thankful if you help me because I'm struggling with this for 3 hours.

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inMutable=true;
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        getApplicationContext().getResources(), 
        R.drawable.test1, 
        options);
```

Comment: What technology are you using? Code??

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

a = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0);

while(True):
    ret,img=cam.read();
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = a.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces :
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Face", img);
    if(cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q')):
        break;
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```